# Load excel file to selected table name

Tags: django, django-models

Learning django and this might be a very basic question.. please excuse..

I have created a dropdown in my django app linked to a database model column that has list of table names in my database.

I want to allow the user to select the table name in the drop down and then browse to an xlsx file and load the data to the table.

Need your expert advise on the below..

1. Is it possible to create a view that can load excel data dynamically to the model based on table name selecred?

   2. Is it possible to validate the colmn names first before performing data load to avoid issues?
   3. Is it possible to perform truncate and load vs append data by allowing the user to choose the action.

Thank you very much for your guidance and also appreciate if you can put me in the right direction with some samples, examples or documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very well in Django. Suppose you have a django model `SampleModel` and you are uploading a csv file. You can iterate over different entries of the csv file as follow:

```
csv_file = request.FILES['file']
```

then you need to decode it using `UTF-8` as follow:

```
data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
```

Then you can just iterate over the csv file and create entries as follow:

```
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
    _, created = SampleModel.objects.create(...)
```

or you can try bulk create as follow:

```
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
sample_model_list = []
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
    _, created = sample_model_list.append(SampleModel(...))
SampleModel.objects.bulk_create(sample_model_list)
```

Bulk create in general is fast and more efficient. You can read more about it from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). also, above code is inspired from this [link](https://medium.com/@simathapa111/how-to-upload-a-csv-file-in-django-3a0d6295f624). So, you can read it and have a better look.

As of validation the data, you can have a serializer where you can put the data from csv, validate the data and create entries afterwards:

```
serializer = SampleModelSerializer(data={...})
if serialzier.is_valid():
    SampleModel.objects.create(**serialzier.validated_data)
else:
    print(serializer.errors)
```

At certain I have use 3 dots to denote entries you have in csv corresponding the model fields, so you can fill it accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer!, I started to write something up about just importing pandas and using their read_excel function, or looking at django-excel, but doing the above would be much more efficient.  I'm a novice, so sometimes I'll use those to avoid file handling check the data before going into the model.

Comment: Can tha same be implemented for xlsx files too? please advise.

Comment: No, xlsx is a complex format than csv. It includes other stuff related to excel. So, not it is not directly not possible to do same thing for xlsx but you can try converting xlsx to csv(not sure if there is direct way to do this).